# Parse fixed width file and lookup those parsed values against Oracle Db

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, files

Files arrive within a specific time window (midnight-0600hrs EST) and get saved to the orders directory on the Linux host. these files are stored in a zip format. usually around 30 files are expected on each business day during that time window.

There are other files that come in during this time window as well and get saved to the same orders directory with the same zip file name. So the first thing to do would be to unzip the zip file to check if the file of our interest - desc1234.NNN - is present in those zip files.

The next requirement is to parse all those 30 files post the time arrival window for a specific field on the file -  field position on the file: 20-34 - for a specific record type 999. There are multiple record types 999 on the file(apart from other record types).

Using the field (alt_ord_id) parsed from these files, lookup a specific column `ord_id` on the orders table in the Oracle db and display the ord_id along with the alt_ord_id and the file name.

The Oracle Db table structure is as below (displaying only 2 columns of interest) :

sql>desc orders;

ord_id varchar2(15);
alt_ord_id varchar2(15);

Expected Final O/p:

File_Name     Alt_ord_id            Ord_id

---

desc1234.001 123456789012345        ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
desc1234.002 234567890123456        BCDEFGHIJKLMNOP

There are around 30 of these daily files expected and each file contain around 10-15 record types of 999.

- dir: `orders`
- zip file name: `customer_orders_YYYYMMDDHHMISS.zip`
- file name: `desc1234.NNN` (`NNN` is a sequence number)
- file format: fixed width text

1. I'm using the following to read the filename from zip file to confirm if it has the file `desc1234.NNN`

   ```
   for zip_file in *.zip; do if [$(unzip -l $zip_file|grep -c "desc1234") -ne 0]; then filename="`zipinfo -1 customer_orders.zip`"; echo $filename; fi; done
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   desc1234.001
   ```
2. Command#2

   ```
   cat desc1234.123|grep "999"|cut -c 20-34|awk 'BEGIN {printf("(")} (for i=1; i<=NF;i++) { printf("'\''%s'\'',",$i} } '|awk '{gsub(/,$/,")"}; print}'> test2.txt
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   ('123456789012345','234567890123456','345678901234567')
   ```

I think I need to combine (1) and (2) above to send a final string such as

```
('123456789012345','234567890123456','345678901234567')
```

to lookup against a table in Oracle db.

How do I achieve combining (1) and (2) when I lookout for files that have processed in the 12-6am time window?

Input file:

```
001ORDERS20211117   72222 ORDERS CYCLE 001 202111170320
001 124 ABC XYZ
002 231 WASHING CYCLE
999 456 YUIHY      123456789012345  
011 123 ABCD XYZ
012 786 MACHINE
999 654            234567890123456
```

[image: desc1234.001]

Comment: 1. you don't need cat, grep,or cut if you're already using awk. 2. you need to show a small but representative sample of your input if you expect anyone to be able to help. anonymise the data if it contains any personal information. i.e. change names, identifiers, credit card numbers, etc

Comment: 3. shell is the wrong language for this. `awk` is sub-optimal too.  `perl` would be a better choice, as it has an [Archive::Zip](https://metacpan.org/release/Archive-Zip) library module for working with zip files, and [DBI](https://dbi.perl.org/) and [DBD::Oracle](https://metacpan.org/release/DBD-Oracle) for working directly with oracle databases (and DBI supports placeholders in sql statements too, so you don't need to worry about properly quoting values).    If you're using linux, all of these perl modules are probably packaged for your distro.  Otherwise, install them with `cpan`.

Comment: @cas- Please refer the sample input file - desc1234.001 - below:

001ORDERS20211117 72222 ORDERS CYCLE 001 202111170320
001 124 ABC XYZ
002 231 WASHING CYCLE
999 456 YUIHY      123456789012345 
011 123 ABCD XYZ
012 786 MACHINE
999 654            234567890123456

Comment: please edit your question and add it there.  it's basically useless in a comment, no line-feeds or formatting.

Comment: @cas - I have updated the query to add an image of the input file since I didn't see an option to attach the file. I hope this helps.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.  Just copy and paste the text.  An image of text is completely useless. I can't copy it to my system and use it for testing any script.

Comment: I have pasted the file text into the question and formatted it. Looks neat now. I hope that helps now.

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input (the text block under `Input file:`) so we can clearly see your requirements and have something we can copy/paste to test with.

Comment: @cas - Truly appreciate your efforts and time to go through the question, share your thoughts and most importantly helping with a starting point. I'm looking at this today after past 2 hectic days at work :)  I have edited the original question to put in more details around the db table structure and the final expected o/p since you mentioned those details were missing. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the script below as a starting point.

BTW, you don't say what kind of unix you're running, what shell you're using, or what version of `awk` you have.  I'm going to assume that you're running Linux (or something else with GNU core utilities installed), bash, and GNU awk.  And the [infozip](http://www.info-zip.org/UnZip.html) version of `unzip`.  If these assumptions are incorrect, you'll have to adapt the bash+awk script to suit your system.

```
$ cat process-zip-files.sh 
#!/bin/bash

# create a temporary directory
# mktemp is in GNU coreutils
td="$(mktemp -d)"

for zf in *.zip; do
  # unzip options: -qq = very quiet, -o = don't prompt for overwrite,
  # -d = directory to unzip files into.
  unzip -qq -o -d "$td" "$zf" '*.[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
done

# Process each unzipped text file individually
# This awk script requires GNU awk.  The ENDFILE pattern
# is a GNU extension to awk.
awk '/^999 / { data[i++] = substr($0,20,34) };

     ENDFILE {
       out="";
       for (i in data) { out = out data[i] "," };
       sub(/,$/,"",out);
       print "(" out ")";
       delete data;
     }' "$td/"*

# delete the temporary directory and everything in it
rm -rf "$td/"
```

Note that the script assumes that there is at least one `999` record in each text file.
If this is not the case, you'll have to check if the `data` array has at least one element in the ENDFILE block, otherwise it will output a line with just `()` for those text files.

This is a bare-minimum script and doesn't do any error-checking or handling, nor does it make any attempt to handle unusual or complicating conditions.

Sample output (after creating a zip file with your sample text inside it):

```
$ ./process-zip-files.sh 
(123456789012345,234567890123456)
```

---

A better script would be written in `perl`.   It would set up a connection to the Oracle database (using open the [DBI](https://dbi.perl.org/) and [DBD::Oracle](https://metacpan.org/release/DBD-Oracle).

Then it would open today's batch of zip file(s) (using the [Archive::Zip](https://metacpan.org/release/Archive-Zip) module) and process each .NNN text file inside them.   Using the data from the text files, it would construct an SQL statement and send it to the Oracle DB.

This statement could be a search, an insert, an update, a deletion - anything that you can normally do with SQL.

`python` would be another good implementation language - it also has library modules for interacting with zip files and with databases such as Oracle.

There **are** ways of interacting with Oracle and other SQL databases directly from bash or other shells.....but the amount of screwing around with spaces and quoting that you have to do makes it an annoyingly tedious and frustrating programming exercise, prone to annoying little problems.   It's much easier to just learn the minimal subset of perl (or python) that you need to do the job....and then once you've done it once, it's easy to do similar tasks in future.

It's almost 2 am here and I need some sleep, so I don't have time to write even a basic version of such a script at them moment.  And your question doesn't really give any details on what you want to do with the data in Oracle, anyway.

---

PS: from the two sample bits of shell code you posted in your Question, it seems as if you like to do things with one-liners.  One-liners are useful, but they're not always the best solution to a problem....and, often they're a bad solution.   Don't be afraid of writing scripts in languages like awk or perl - using them, either stand-alone or as part of a shell script, is how unix & linux is meant to be used.

Trying to do data processing in shell, with long & complicated pipelines of many commands is pretty much guaranteed to be harder than writing a custom tool in awk or perl....and the shell pipeline is very likely to be much more fragile, as well as certain to be several orders of magnitude slower.  For small data files and simple processing tasks, performance probably doesn't matter much.  For lots of data and/or complicated processing, it can mean the difference between a few seconds and many hours of run-time.

---

Here's a few examples of doing the same thing in perl using the `Archive::Zip` and/or `DBI` & `DBD` modules.  These perl scripts don't need a temporary directory to unzip the .zip files into because they read the matching files directly from the .zip archive.

The first example just replicates what the bash + awk script does:

```
$ cat process-zip-files.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use Archive::Zip;

# First arg is the source directory. defaults to ./
my $dir = shift // '.';

foreach my $zf (glob "$dir/*.zip") {
  # open the zip file
  my $zip = Archive::Zip->new($zf);

  # get the list of files ending with a dot and at least one digit
  my @txt = grep { /\.\d+$/ } $zip->memberNames();

  # iterate over each matching filename
  foreach my $f (@txt) {
    my @data = ();

    # Iterate over each line of the file ($f).  This code is fine
    # for smallish files, but it would be better to use the
    # Archive::Zip::MemberRead module for large files to avoid
    # reading the entire file into memory at once.
    foreach (split /\n/, $zip->contents($f)) {
      if (m/^999\s/) {
        # perl substr offsets start at 0, not 1.  So the
        # next line grabs 15 chars, starting from char 20
        # and adds the string to the @data array.
        push @data, substr($_,19,15);
      }
    };

    # Now do something with the data from this file
    @data = map { "'$_'" } @data; # quote each element of @data
    print "(", join(",",@data), ")\n";

  }  # end of current member file
} # end of current zipfile
```

```
$ ./process-zip-files.pl 
('123456789012345','234567890123456')
```

Instead of just printing the data, you can interact with the database directly. I can only give vague and fairly useless examples here because I have no idea what your database table structure looks like, or what you actually want to do with the data extracted from the .NNN files.

```
$ cat process-zip-files-sql.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use Archive::Zip;
use Archive::Zip::MemberRead;
use DBI;

# First arg is the source directory. defaults to ./
my $dir = shift // '.';

# I don't have Oracle, and I couldn't be bothered setting up
# a database, table, and login account on mysql or postgres
# for this example, so I'll use SQLite.  Other databases are
# just as easy to connect to, but the connect() call will
# require other details like hostname, port, login, password,
# etc.
#
# Set up a database handle ($dbh) to the sqlite db called
# "notoracle.sqlite3":

my $dbname='notoracle.sqlite3';
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$dbname","","");

foreach my $zf (glob "$dir/*.zip") {
  my $zip = Archive::Zip->new($zf);
  my @txt = grep { /\.\d+$/ } $zip->memberNames();

  foreach my $f (@txt) {
    my @data = ();

    # This example uses Archive::Zip::MemberRead, just to show
    # how to use it.
    my $fh  = Archive::Zip::MemberRead->new($zip, $f);
    while (defined(my $l = $fh->getline())) {
      if ($l =~ m/^999\s/) {
        push @data, substr($l,19,15);
      }
    };
    $fh->close();

    # Example 1: print matching records (each element needs to be
    # quoted when using IN, can't use placeholders):

    my @qdata = map { "'$_'" } @data; # quote each element of @data
    my $values = join(",",@qdata);
    my $sql = "select * from mytable where myfield in ($values)";
    print join(",", $dbh->selectrow_array($sql)),"\n";

    # Example 2 - using a placeholder ?, one element of @data
    # at a time.  There is no need to quote each element of
    # the @data array because placeholders handle quoting
    # automagically if and when required, depending on the data
    # type of the database field.

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare('select * from mytable where myfield = ?');
    foreach my $d (@data) {
      while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array($sql,undef,$d)) {
        print join(",",@row), "\n";
      }
    }
  }  # end of current member file
} # end of current zipfile
```

There's no sample output for this one because it's a non-functional conceptual example. This code is untested for the same reason and may have minor errors. It does compile OK with `perl -w -c process-zip-files-sql.pl` but that's no guarantee that it actually works or that it does anything useful.

Comment: If you need the numbers quoted, replace the `for (i in data)` line with:  `for (i in data) { out = out "'\''" data[i] "'\''," };`